# How to use React Native Rxjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, rxjs, observable

```
export async function getAllStock() {
    try {
        let data;
        await Axios.get("stocks/find-all", config)
            .pipe(retry(2))
            .subscribe(
                async (response) => {
                    return await response.data;
                },
                (error) => console.log(error)
            );
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/zhaosiyang/axios-observable
I am using this library to get records from API in my React Native project

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            console.log(await getAllStock());
        };
        getData();
    }, []);
```

Actually my goal is to subscribe to response data,response data should be subscribed and changes should be reflected on the screens instantly. But always undefined response data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to use Axios with observables to fetch data in your React Native project. However, the code you provided has some issues. Here's how you can modify your code to properly handle the observable and get the response data: 1. Install the necessary dependencies: First, make sure you have the required dependencies installed. You mentioned that you are using the axios-observable library, so you'll need to install it:

```
npm install axios axios-observable rxjs
```

2. Modify your `getAllStock` function:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AxiosObservable } from 'axios-observable';
import Axios from 'axios';

export function getAllStock() {
  const axiosObservable = AxiosObservable.create({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'stocks/find-all',
    headers: { ...config.headers }, // Assuming config is defined somewhere.
  }).pipe(retry(2));

  return axiosObservable;
}
```

In this code, we create an AxiosObservable and pipe the retry operator to it. The function now returns the observable.

3. Modify your `useEffect`:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getAllStock } from './your-module'; // Import your getAllStock function

function YourComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = getAllStock().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response.data); // Handle the response data here
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

    // Don't forget to unsubscribe when the component unmounts.
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  // Rest of your component code
}
```

Now, when you call `getAllStock()`, it will return an observable that you can subscribe to. When the response data is received, it will be logged, and you can handle it as needed. Make sure to adjust the import paths and incorporate the code into your project structure as necessary.